# stunnel smtp tls frontend server/proxy for remote backend postfix

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp, google-cloud-platform, stunnel

I'm running stunnel in server mode and listening on port 587 and trying to connect to a remote postfix server running on port 25.

NB: the two servers are connected via zerortier, which may or may not be relevant to the issue.

```
DEBUG = 7

[ssmtp]
protocol = smtp
accept = google_cloud_internal_ip:587
connect = remote_zerotier_postfix_ip:25
cert = /etc/stunnel/domain.pem
```

I thought this would set up stunnel to handle the TLS handshake and terminate the TLS connection, while proxing to the backend postfix server without requiring postfix to worry about TLS. But I'm getting LOG3[0]: STARTTLS expected when stunnel tries to connect to postfix. If I put stunnel in client mode, then it doesn't negotiate the incoming TLS (right?).

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't direct it to port 25. Setup `submission` service on Postfix (e.g. on the port 587) and connect there. And, I think it expects your Postfix will have TLS also set up and STARTTLS enabled.

Comment: If you remove the stunnel piece and let postfix handle the TLS, what's the preferred method for connecting the backend postfix to the public-facing frontend server? I started off using haproxy, but it doesn't handle smtp TLS  AFAIK. The backend postfix is behind a NAT so that's why I am using zerotier to connect to a public frontend.

Comment: I don't understand your architecture then. In principle Postfix is self-contained; what is "frontend", what it does in your setup? // That said, there is no problem operating Postfix behind standard NAT. For accepting connections from outside you forward (DNAT) ports to it (25, 587, 465, as required). For making connections to outside you masquerade (SNAT) your Postfix into some public address. You may need to specify that public IP address in a [`proxy_interfaces` configuration parameter](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#proxy_interfaces) in `main.cf`.

Comment: I think basically the problem might also be that Generally postfix won’t allow clear text authentication. Since your using stunnel to offload explicit TLS (but postfix doesn’t know that) it requests the client to upgrade their clear text channel to a secure one with STARTSSL https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS (which probably makes no sense to the client that has already established a TLS encrypted channel to your stunnel daemon)

Comment: [`smtpd_tls_security_level`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_security_level) setting `none` or `may` will permit authentication even when STARTTLS wasn't used.